# Programmatically configure multiple Azure resource diagnostic settings

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-diagnostics

Since a few months the Azure portal allows you to configure multiple diagnostic settings. This allows you to configure multiple different target services to push the diagnostic logs to.

Microsoft documented the workings of the diagnostic settings in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-of-diagnostic-logs). But it doesn't seem to explain how you would programmatically add multiple diagnostic settings.

For some of our Azure services, I want to setup multple diagnostic settings, so that I can send the diagnostics to several different OMS Log Analytics workspaces at the same time. I can do this via the Azure portal, as can be seen in the screenshot below. 
[image: Example of multiple diagnostic settings, where each setting contains a different OMS Log Analytics workspace]

But I would like to know how to do this programmatically, using ARM templates, Powershell or something else.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Azure rest api could do this, please refer this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/servicediagnosticsettings/createorupdate

Comment: In request boby, you could use different name, PoweShell cmdlet could not use specify name.

Comment: Thank you Shengbao, I wil experiment with this. It's just unfortunate that we cannot do this with ARM templates or Powershell.

Comment: Yes, currently, you could not use PowerShell to do this. Does API work for you?